# UTC string to DateTime exception

Tags: c#, .net

I am getting this exception:

```
String was not recognized as a valid DateTime
```

for this string:

```
2012-10-03T10:41:22.988401+01:00
```

using this code:

```
DateTime.ParseExact(TheStringAbove, "o", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None);
```

I know that the DateTime string is UTC. Is there anything wrong with the code? Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That string is *not* UTC - it's explictly got something saying it's an hour ahead of UTC! That's what the +01:00 means. You really need to think about that part carefully.

The reason it's failing is that doesn't quite conform to the ["o" format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx#Roundtrip):

> The "O" or "o" standard format specifier corresponds to the "yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss'.'fffffffK" custom format string for DateTime values

Note that there are 7 fs there, but you've only got 6 decimal places. `2012-10-03T10:41:22.9884010+01:00` works fine - but you'll still need to check whether it actually means what you want it to mean, based on your expectation that this is really UTC.

Comment: Thanks. The generated string is beyond my control ... so I have to ask the data provider to fix this.