# Exception when converting UTC string to DateTime

Tags: c#, .net

I receive the datetime string below from a web service and try to transform it into a UTC datetime object but an exception is thrown.

```
try
{
    string ReceivedDateTimeString = "2012-10-09T07:42:13.409191Z";
    DateTime TransformedReceivedDateTimeString = DateTime.ParseExact(ReceivedDateTimeString, "o", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None);
}
catch (Exception e)
}
```

Why is an exception thrown? Is there something wrong with the format of the string or with my transformation?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12705874/utc-string-to-datetime-exception - sorry can't use same question title

Comment: IMHO the downvotes are a bit harsh.  Neither of the linked questions gives an answer that clearly applies to this scenario.

Comment: Thanks Joe - that's why I created a new question.

Comment: You still have only 6 decimal places, that part of Jon Skeet's answer still applies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about this:

```
DateTime TransformedReceivedDateTimeString = DateTime.Parse(ReceivedDateTimeString).ToUniversalTime();
```

Comment: I guess you would have to define that it is suppose to be UTC as well?!!! So I do not see much difference.

Comment: You just need to convert to UTC

Comment: Do you mean: DateTime.Parse(ReceivedDateTimeString).ToUniversalTime()?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
string ReceivedDateTimeString = "2012-10-09T07:42:13.409191Z";
DateTime TransformedReceivedDateTimeString = 
    DateTime.ParseExact(ReceivedDateTimeString, 
                       "yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss'.'FFFFFFFK", 
                       CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, 
                       DateTimeStyles.RoundTripKind);
```

The [documentation for the "o" format specifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx#Roundtrip) states that:

> The "O" or "o" standard format specifier corresponds to the "yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss'.'fffffffK" custom format string for DateTime values and to the "yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss'.'fffffffzzz" custom format string for DateTimeOffset values.

I.e. 7 decimals, not 6 as in your string.

> The formatted string can be parsed back by using the DateTimeParse(String, IFormatProvider, DateTimeStyles) or DateTimeParseExact method if the styles parameter is set to DateTimeStyles.RoundtripKind.

I.e. you need to specify DateTimeStyles.RoundtripKind.

In the above, I've used "FFF..." rather than "fff..." as this will accept a variable number of decimals (missing trailing decimals are treated as zero).  This is to conform to the principle of being "tolerant on input, strict on output".

Also I've specified DateTimeStyles.RoundtripKind to preserve the Kind property when parsing (Utc in this case).  If you don't do this, the result will be converted to local time.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you were given the correct answer the last time by Jon Skeet: [UTC string to DateTime exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12705874/utc-string-to-datetime-exception)

> Note that there are 7 fs there, but you've only got 6 decimal places.

It's the same error now. You've got three possible solutions:

1. As you stated on your previous question ([comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12705874/utc-string-to-datetime-exception#comment17154938_12705940)), you could have your data
   provider send you the data on the standard format.
2. If you don't have access to the data, you could change the style parameter to a custom format:
   `"yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.ffffffK"`
3. Or, you could add another decimal at the end to follow the standard format:
   `"2012-10-09T07:42:13.4091910Z";`

Change the standard format

Comment: If I'm trying to parse input that presumably comes from an external source, it's not very helpful to say "change the input".